# copies of primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, entities

I understand that in the `attendances` table there are copies of primary keys (probably from the decomposed entities). What's the difference between `PK` and `PK, FK` as you can see in the row with `student_id` inside the `attendances` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Attendance` table the `PRIMARY KEY` isn't simple - it's being composed from two columns:

```
student_id, running_id
```

As I understand, this means that each student can't be an attendant of the same course run twice. And the `student_id` in `Attendance` table is a `FOREIGN KEY` to the students for a data consistency. Can't say for sure why the `running_id` isn't the `FOREIGN KEY` either.